# Springboot JPA HQL Query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, mapstruct

Im tinkering to learn more about springboot jpa and mapstruct

I got 2 entity class and using pgadmin4 for postgresql.

PostQuestions have a foreign key userId to Users table

I currently want to do a @Query to get all the Users and PostQuestions table

Map them to my frontend can display the question being posted and by who attached the the json response on how it should look where i will map and display all the questions and the email of the user but for generic purposes im going to be querying both table and just pick what values i want to display as i want to learn more on mapstruct mapping as well

But im facing errors and am currently lost on how to rectify im unfamiliar with the stacktrace errors and not know where i should begin my rectification

> Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in
> io.tracker.track_app.repos.UserRepository defined in
> @EnableJpaRepositories declared on DomainConfig: Could not create
> query for public abstract java.util.List
> io.tracker.track_app.repos.UserRepository.getUsersAndPosts(); Reason:
> Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List
> io.tracker.track_app.repos.UserRepository.getUsersAndPosts()
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't compare test
> expression of type [Users] with element of type
> [BasicSqmPathSource(userId : Integer)]

I've attach my entity and dto classes along with the repository where i wrote my JPA @Query

The image is the json response that my frontend will receive to display the values that im going to pick and display
[image]

**PostQuestions**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "posts", schema = "public")
public class PostQuestion {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "post_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "primary_sequence",
            sequenceName = "primary_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY
    )
    private Integer postId;

    @Column(name="questionnum", nullable = false)
    private Long questionnum;

    @Column(name="title", nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(name="url", nullable = false)
    private String url;

    @Column(name="content" , nullable = false)
    private String content;

    @Column(name = "timestamp")
    private LocalDate timestamp;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private Users userId;
```

**PostQuestionDTO**

```
public class PostQuestionDTO {

private Integer postId;

@NotNull
private Long questionnum;

@NotNull
@Size(max = 255)
private String title;

@NotNull
@Size(max = 255)
private String url;

@NotNull
@Size(max = 255)
private String content;

private LocalDate timestamp;

private Integer userId;

private String email;
```

**Users**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", schema="public")
public class Users {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "primary_sequence",
            sequenceName = "primary_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY
    )
    private Integer userId;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "role", nullable = false)
    private String role;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userId")
    private List<PostQuestion> postId;
```

**UserDTO**

```
public class UserDTO {

private Integer userId;

@NotNull
@Size(max = 255)
private String email;

@NotNull
@Size(max = 255)
private String password;

@NotNull
@Size(max = 255)
private String role;

private List<PostQuestionDTO> postQuestionDTO;
```

**User Repository**

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Integer> {


    @Query("SELECT p, u FROM PostQuestion p INNER Join Users u ON p.userId = u.userId")
    List<Users> getUsersAndPosts();

}
```

**Mapper class**

```
@Mapper
public interface UserMapper {

    UserDTO mapToDTO(Users user);

    Users mapToEntity(UserDTO userDTO);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you're `JPQL` query is querying the wrong base table. Your user repository is mapped to the User entity:

```java
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Integer> {

}
```

Naturally, all your queries need to go through the base table to all other entities linked to the `User` entity.

So, one solution could be to query all users where `PostQuestions` is not null using a derived query.

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Integer> {
   
   List<Employee> getUsersByPostIdNotNull();

}
```